# Can we automate creation of google api console project with google cloud messaging enabled?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are creating a mobile device management solution. We want to use Google cloud messaging(GCM) service to push notifications from server.

To use GCM, we need to create a Google API console project and enable the GCM service. Also, we need to create a server key(API key) in this API console project which is used later to authenticate server to GCM. All the client applications register to GCM using SenderID (generated as soon as the project is created).

Problem:
For each of the customer, we would need to create a google account to provide GCM functionality (not sure if there are other ways). We need to automate the above process (creation of google account, creation of google API console project, enabling service, creation of server key and so on). In other words, customer should not see anything that is happening.

I tried looking for couple of days, I am not able to get much information. 
1. Can we automate this process?
2. If no, do we need to do any license purchases from google to achieve this?

Any other way I can achieve this (enabling GCM for all the customers )?

Note: This is my first question. Apologies if there are any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in such automation (which is certainly not wanted by google). For your need you only create one key on the console, in one project.

You customers register to GCM on the first launch of your app, which gives them a unique (per app & per device) key (regID).

Every time you send them messages (downstream) you target them specifying this regID. Every time your app sends a messages, the regID is automagically added by GCM client, so that your server knows who is sending.

**More precisely:**

- You have several clients, identified by their `clientID`, with an installed tomcat-based server (client server).
- Each client has several users, identified by a `userID` (input on UI, etc). This users are aware of the clientID they belong to. the couple userID/clientID is unique on the central server below.
- You also have a `central server`, connected to GCM/CCS, backed with a DB, forwarding messages between a user and the associated client server.

When a devices registers, it gets the regID from GCM, and sends (via http or xmpp) its userID and associated clientID  to your central servers which stores it, and sends it to the correct client server. Subsequent messages upstream work the same: your messages stanzas contain the userID, which allows to query the DB backing your central server for the clientID, and thus to forward the message to the correct client server.

Downstreams initiated by your clients send a message containing the actions and associated data to you central server, from the userID it checks if the user really belongs to the sending client, get the regID, and sends it to the correct device.

In this proposed architecture you have **one key/project on the Google console, and multiple sets of users, each set being manage by its own server.**

Comment: Issue is that the messages sent to the client application is also by a application owned by customer. Customer will use a server side application(provided by us) with which he is going to push notification to the client applications(also provided by us) that are registered to GCM. 

I might not need new Google account per each customer but I think we might need a different API project for each customer which are created in a Google account owned by my team.

Comment: To summarize, each of our customers will a server which uses GCM to send notification to android device.

Comment: I still believe you should use one key and one project to centralize streams. I suggest that you app allows to declare which of you client it belongs to, and sends it with the regID. Thus you client-installed server could ask you central server which devices it owns, for broadcast, or particular message.

Comment: There is no central server concept in our product. We develop the server piece which runs on tomcat and client piece which runs on android mobiles. These servers support upto 100000 devices. Suppose if I use the same project/same key for all customers, the number of devices registered to GCM with the same project number would be too huge and it might become tough to manage. 

To keep it a bit simpler, we need a different project for each customer. Sorry if I am confusing you :)

Comment: There is no maximum number of devices in a GCM project. **In short:** automating creation tasks in google console is not possible.

Comment: Will it not be a problem if one customer gets the registration ID of the device of the second customer? First customer can send commands to do full wipe from his server to the second customer's device.

It is not common that we get the registration IDs. But the consequence of it is very high as we send various commands to the device.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Your central server receives registration from a device, assorted with your customer id (from UI), and stores it in DB. If you central server receives a message from a device, it gets the associated client ID, so it can forward it to the right server (tomcat one). If you got a message from a client server to forward, just don't forward it if the regID/clientID do not match in DB (it cannot happen since client servers cannot use regID the've never been sent).

Comment: My understanding from your comment is that we are going to check registration id and customer id for security purpose. I like this idea. 

Can you explain me more about what is this customer id ? Is it a user entered value? If so, do we need to restrict duplicate entries? Can we have IMEI number as customer ID? Any additional details.

Comment: You can use a pseudo, an imei, a msisdn, whatever you like so that registration allows you to know what user belongs to which of you customer, to proxy messages correctly. Msisdn and imei are tempting userId, but not reliably queried from all devices. Pseudo demands uniqueness to be taken care of. All this depends on the particular system you are setting up. Concerning your initial question (_Can we automate creation of google api console project with google cloud messaging enabled?_), i think you have the answer: **Nope**.

Comment: Not very sure about the procedure. Can you update the answer with the alternate method? I will accept it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: To sum up: you have several clients, identified by their clientID, with an installed tomcat-based server (client server). Each customer has several users, identified by a userID (input on UI, etc). You also have a central server, connected to GCM/CCS, backed with a DB, forwarding messages between a user and the associated client server.